# Scripting a script that tests a shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, source-code, dash-shell

I have a custom shell and want to test its arithmetic function. I wrote a script to test it and it performs the arithmetic but it is also trying to execute the result as a program.

```
  printf "********************* TEST Arithmetics  ... .\nYou should see the number 4096 below "
    #read _
    valgrind --leak-check=yes ./shell .<< EOF
    $((64 * 64))
    EOF
```

Result: 
`failed to execute 4096: (2: No such file or directory)`

= right answer concatenated with a bug.

The expression `$((64 * 64))` will evaluate if I run the test, but I also get an error message. The strange thing is that I only get this error message if I run the project from inside JetBrain Clion, I don't get it in th terminal if I run my shell in terminal mode instead of automating tests against it.

```
$ $((64 * 64))
Result = 4096
$
```

Do you think the error is in the test or in the shell?

Comment: try to `echo  $((64 * 64))` Your shell might behave different in script-mode

Comment: @LittleByBlue it worked! with `echo` Prints 4096 without the error msg.

Comment: For future reference, this type of question is better suited for... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: bash implements `((...))` as well as `$((...))` for, I presume, just this reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(( 64*64 ))` will literally put 4096 onto the command line and say, go ahead and run it.  Hence the error

```
 failed to execute 4096: (2: No such file or directory)
```

If you just want to perform calculations without printing, remove $. If you do want to print, use `echo $(( 64*64))`